# video do facebook não abre em full screen

Tags: html, facebook, iframe

Copiei o embed do um vídeo do facebook para publicar em meu site, mas quando clico para ampliar full screen ele aumenta a tela do vídeo, porém dentro da div da página. O vídeo não amplia "por cima" da pagina. Isso acontece apenas no navegador google chrome.

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Faindatonova%2Fvideos%2Fvb.224964194534837%2F230602647304325%2F%3Ftype%3D3&show_text=0&width=560" width="560" height="315" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: mobile o browse?

Comment: @Lollipop no browse

Comment: Aparece alguma mensagem de erro no Console, pode ser o Cache do navegador, tente limpar, mas primeiro olhe se tem algum erro no console.

Comment: Não é problema de cache nem exibe erro no console, o vídeo amplia 100% mas dentro da div com a classe container,